# How can I get SwaggerUI/Swashbuckle to send the correct token to my API after authorizing against Azure AD B2C?

Tags: asp.net, swagger, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to implement Azure AD B2C for my application and I want to use SwaggerUI to do some testing. Authentication using SwaggerUI and OAuth2 works and I get logged in to Azure AD B2C, receiving several tokens in return. (I'm using authorization code flow with pkce)

```
{
    "id_token": "<valid token>",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not_before": 1702649151,
    "id_token_expires_in": 3600,
    "profile_info": "<valid token>",
    "scope": "openid",
    "refresh_token": "<valid token>",
    "refresh_token_expires_in": 86400
}
```

However, when I try to call my endpoints they still will not work. I can see from the devtools that it does not send the token correctly in the request. It sets the "Authorization"-header to "Bearer undefined". I have tested several of the solutions from other similar questions, but they don't work.

This is the security requirement I'm currently using:

```
    private static OpenApiSecurityRequirement Oauth2SecurityRequirement =>
        new()
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "oauth2"
                    },
                    Scheme = "oauth2",
                    Name = "oauth2",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header
                },
                new List<string>()
            }
        };
```

(yes I have also tried variants with "bearer" as scheme/id, no difference)

In my `AddSwaggerGen()` config I have the following

```
c.AddSecurityRequirement(Oauth2SecurityRequirement);
c.OperationFilter<GenericOperationFilter>(Oauth2SecurityRequirement);
```

where `c` is the `SwaggerGenOptions` object.

And just for completeness, this is the operation filter:

```
public class GenericOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private readonly OpenApiSecurityRequirement _defaultRequirement;

    public GenericOperationFilter(OpenApiSecurityRequirement defaultRequirement)
    {
        _defaultRequirement = defaultRequirement;
    }
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any())
        {
            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                //same security requirment defined in AddSecurityRequirement
                _defaultRequirement
            };
        }
    }
}
```

So to sum up

- Authenticating against Azure AD B2C works, I get several tokens back
- I get the little lock-icon on both the "Authorize"-button and on the endpoints in SwaggerUI
- When I try to execute an endpoint, it does not send the token in the Authorization header.
  [image: screenshot from swaggerui]

(`/utility/claims` is just an endpoint that dumps the user claims to json)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your security definition in your `Program.cs` file?
You should have something like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "API Title", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "Azure AD Login using OAuth2",
        Name = "AD Login",
        Type = Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            Implicit = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiOAuthFlow()
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "{scope}", "{name}" }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    c.OperationFilter<AuthRequirementOperationFilter>();
});
```

Also, you'll want to make sure that you add the following to the `app` section of your `Program.cs`

```
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API Name");
        c.OAuthClientId("{clientId});
        c.OAuthUsePkce();
        c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
    });
```